# Block selection in tile-based game

Tags: trigonometry

I know that this problem can probably be solved with some basic trig, but for some reason, I can't figure out what exactly to do for the life of me. I'm making a game that's not unlike Terraria (it's basically 2-dimensional Minecraft), and one of the features that's required is block selection based on the location of the mouse relative to the player. This leads to a problem where the distance between two point is known, along with the location of one point and the angle formed by the line between the player and the mouse and a vertical line containing the player. How would I determine the second point?

EDIT:

[image]

The red line connects the mouse (not shown) and the player. The grey block beneath the player is the selected block calculated by the game. Normally, this would contain the continuation of the red line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, let $(x,y)$ be the first point, $r$ the distance desired, and $\theta$ the angle to the desired point relative to the vertical. Then you want (depending on your orientation change the sign) $$(x+r\sin\theta,y\pm r\cos\theta)$$
Note that this only works if $\theta$ can range all the way round a circle. Knowing just the angle and not which direction it is measured in leads to an ambiguity $x\pm\cdots$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it's only applicable if $θ$ ranges around a circle? Would it be such if when the line of sight of the player is parallel to the vertical, $θ$ is 180?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. A problem arises if you have $\theta$ being the same when you measure 50 degrees left and 50 degrees right, for instance.

Comment: I've implemented the equation you suggested along with my own for calculating the angle, and while it usually works fine, there are certain cases in which it fails to select the proper block, as shown in the image I added. I believe this is due to my angle-calculation equation. Do you see anything wrong with it? $θ$ = arctan(($mouseX$ - $playerX$), ($mouseY$ - $playerY$)

Comment: I had a typo which I fixed rather late, a missing $r$. Is that it? The arctangent looks fine.

Comment: Hmm, just realized that it's clearly the $x$ coordinate which is wrong. I suggest printing out the $\theta$ value. Does $r$ change?

Comment: Could be a bug elsewhere ofc. Is it anything to do with the fact that there are no blocks in the selected direction? Or is the relative scaling of your coordinate system and the mouse dodgy? It's very difficult to figure it out without debugging, just getting a printout of the values used.

Comment: I've figured it out. For some reason, I was casting the x-distance to an int, causing it to think it was directly on top of the player. I realized this after taking your advice and printing out $θ$. There was actually another cause, which was a measure I had taken when I was using atan as opposed to arctan so as not to divide by zero. Thanks for your help.